# Performance in migrating a lot of data from the same DB to different DB using application BL

Tags: c#, .net, performance, sql-server-2008, data-migration

I've this problem. I've an application that, each 15 minutes, downloads a file from the net and bulkcopies it into a DB.

Users of my app subscribe to this file so they signal us that they want to "copy" this file into their databases. I wrote "copy" because I should apply some business logic to this Data before putting on their database. This business logic is customer dependent.

The problem is that the starting database contains something like changed 100.000 rows each 15 minutes (some are new records, some are updated and some are deleted).

How would you tackle this problem? I tried following the normal development process:

1. foreach customer
2. take new data --> apply business logic for that user --> put on his DB
3. take upd data --> apply BL --> update his DB
4. take del data --> apply BL --> remove from his DB

But it takes too much. Far far away from 15 minutes. Sometimes it takes hour for a single user.

What would you do?

Thanks,
Marco

Comment: Could you provide some piece of code.. how to get data from file->BL->DB? So that we can find some better approach after reviewing your code.

Comment: This is on SqlServer2008. Suppose I've a database composed by two tables: OLD and NEW. OLD contains the old version of file, while NEW contains the most recent version. The file is downloaded. Before importing the file into NEW I empty the OLD table, copy data from NEW to OLD and empty NEW table. Then I bcp to NEW. I then run three queries to find the differences. Then, after this, I cycle on subscribed users and apply BL (convert records into POCO objects substantially) and update (adding, removing and updating) basing queries on the differences computed before. IS this enough? Thanks

Comment: Some questions that may help to guide: how many subscribers? Are you running it sequentially? If running parallel, how many threads are you using? By "their database", did you mean different schemas on the same server, or those databases are at customer's premises? How complex is that BL? How many indexes are on that table?

Answer (score 1):

100.000 rows doesn't sound too much.

It depends on your business logic, but if it is some data transformation you can consider doing SSIS package (in terms of MS SQL Server, other RDBMS have other tools) to import your data.

You also can thing of taking advantage from parallelism, say, have several threads (or even virtual machines) working for you: just partition the file and process all the partitions simultaneously. Even implementing a simple map/reduce algorithm may help.

In any way, do some performance measurement, you really want to know WHY your data processing is SO slow. Probably something in your code can be optimized A LOT.

100.000 rows an hour is ridiculously slow, something wrong is going on there (unless you have a heavy and super complicated business logic you need to perform on each row of course)

Comment: I agree. 100.000 rows is nothing! The question is: do you think that there is a better solution than this? Like avoiding BL and writing directly on DB an simulating BL effects is some other ways?

Comment: @Marconline As I told you: it depends on what you are doing. If it is a simple data bulk load - go for SSIS. If there is a BL involved then I strongly don't recommend you to bypass it even if it seems simplier, just because you will have to duplicate this BL in your data transformation scripts => functionality duplication => problems with maintenance => bugs. In the BL scenario definitely have your BL involved, but do some parallel processing to speed it up.

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to say without seeing the code but you could try profiling your code with something like [Ants Performance Profiler](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-performance-profiler/) to try to identify where the slow down is occurring. If you don't want to use that, I believe Visual Studio 2010 contains a profiling tool.

Obviously you would want to run your profiling against a debug or staging build rather than your production system.

If you believe that it's a database speed issue, you might want to look at how you're doing your inserts and whether any indexes or triggers are affecting DB insert speeds.

Comment: I know Ants and I really think that's a great tool. Would you suggest it?

Comment: Yes, definitely. It's great for tracking down performance and memory issues that you're otherwise unable to find.